# Use JTS topology in JavaFx

Tags: java, buffer, javafx, jts

I have some polygon in jts topology library.
if I want to draw on javafx pane I do:

```
 Polygon poly=new Polygon();//javafx
 //g is geometry of jts
    for (Coordinate coord : g.getCoordinates())
    {
        poly.getPoints().addAll(coord.x, coord.y);
    }
```

and got extra four edges that are not expected:
[image]

but the same data look good in test builder:
[image]

what is wrong? order of traversing the geometry?
any ideas?

Ok I found that the cause of problem is that this polygon has holes.
Unexpected lines are jumps to not connected parts of this polygon.
How to draw polygon with holes in javafx?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved:
to get shell and holes use getInternalRingN, getExternalRingN
and in JAVAFX first create shell poly and seperately holes polygon

then assign shell to myShape and use Path.substract(myShape, anyHole)